# Change logo position in actiobar, landscape

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've a custom actionbar layout, with an imageview centered.
while the phone is in vertical position, the logo is centered, but no matter what i'm trying to do, I can't make it to be centered in landscape position.
I even try to set a different layout for landscape, and put the logo on the left, but it doesn't affect it.

How can i make the logo be centered (or align left) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this line. 
android:orderInCategory= "3"

play with number to set the logo, use smaller number to set logo to the left side.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I don't use any menu. I have only a custom layout with imageView